# Aligning Facebook Like Button

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am a noobie wed dev. I added a Facebook recommend/share button to my website but I am unaware how to align it horizontally/vertically. It comes with an id tag that I put into my CSS (and I edited with `margin-left`, `margin-top`, etc) but no changes can be seen that are made.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/getbarterly" data-width="450"
     data-colorscheme="dark"  data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" 
     data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fb-like {
    margin-left: -350px;
}
```

Comment: Show off some code. You seem to be on the right track but maybe you just overlooked something.

Comment: What do you mean `"how to align it horizontally/vertically"`?

Comment: I would like for it to sit underneath the "Get me bartering!" box. http://getbarterly.com/5/

Comment: @sukhmen Please provide the minimal amount of code to reproduce your issue in the question itself if you're seeking help. You can create a simplified version on something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can better understand your problem in a simplified way

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EdPfVDUnC4

Comment: For some reason when I enter the code into jsfiddle and choose run, the edits are made. Anyone know what might be the issue why these changes aren't reflected when I make the edits into my FTP?

Comment: I figured it out! I accidentally had an extra bracket above the code I was entering into my stylesheet. Stupid mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example here using the same markup: http://jsfiddle.net/brunomuller/yzex8pgx/6/.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-width="450"
 data-colorscheme="dark"  data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" 
 data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

As you can see, the margin works just fine. Maybe it's another issue that we can help only if you show us some working code.

You can try wrapping the .fb-like with another div, and apply all the styling on it, so you are only using your classes, and making the code more reusable.
Also, you have an extra closing div tag on the example.

Comment: I figured it out! I accidentally had an extra bracket above the code I was entering into my stylesheet. Stupid mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try absolute positioning the div and using top / left or bottom / right.

```
.fb-like {
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 200px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute

hope this works :)

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, we have no idea what the OP (original poster) actually wants. Also please use a more reputable source like Mozilla or W3 (which is *not affiliated with W3Schools*)

Comment: What's wrong with w3schools?  Also there is nothing wrong with guessing what the "OP" wants... A vote down wasn't really necessary.

Comment: "For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on. "  The "OP" claimed they are new to web development, and this paragraph states that it can be a good learning experience for beginners.  Anyways does it really matter?   Its still a site with extra information.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for the link I was not aware of this web pages. They look really nice.

Comment: Is it a problem with your css code, or can the css not find the class?  try changing a value you know works, like the background-color and if it changes the background color then we know its a problem with the css code I gave you, if the color doesn't change then the css isn't affecting the class.

Comment: @IanWise Read [his comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798481/aligning-facebook-like-button/25798673?noredirect=1#comment40353532_25798481). Your post doesn't do anything to that extent

Comment: Didn't see that comment...  Why don't you post an answer?  Instead of just commenting on mine that my answers aren't correct.

Comment: For some reason when I enter the code into jsfiddle and choose run, the edits are made. Anyone know what might be the issue why these changes aren't reflected when I make the edits into my FTP?